# Form designer inconsistent in control display style for updated project

Tags: delphi, controls, properties, delphi-2009, themes

I've got a project that I started in Turbo Delphi, which I recently updated to D2009, and I've noticed a bit of a quirk in the form designer.  All the old forms have a Win98 style applied to them. The buttons are gray with sharp square edges, for example. But any new form I've created since the upgrade displays its controls in WinXP style.  If I copy a control from an old form and paste it to a new one, the style changes.  At runtime, all controls from all forms are shown in XP style.

Any idea what's causing my old forms to show in an old style? I've looked through the properties list, but nothing jumps out at me.  But there's obviously something, and it's persistent because saving and reloading doesn't change it.  Anyone know where this property is and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You should enable run time themes.

Did you check?

```
Project | Options | Application | [  ]  Enable Run Time Themes
```

Comment: It's enabled, and my question is about design-time appearance anyway.

Answer (score 1):

looks at the uses clause in both a old form and a new one, there may be something diffrent. i know in delphi 7 you had to add xpman (or somerthing like that) to get the windows skin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the dfm files? Sometimes there is something there that is not shown in the propertylist.

Comment: Nothing there either.  Whatever this is, it's hiding in some out-of-the-way corner of my project...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a stray Ctl3D (sp?) setting in your dfm?

Answer (score 0):

Well using D2007,

had the same issue on my run time packages. They may where create using D5  or D7.

To fix this issue: simple add a "XP Theme ManiFest" to your culprit package "res" file.

Example of a D2007 manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity
    type="win32"
    name="CodeGear RAD Studio"
    version="11.0.2902.10471" 
    processorArchitecture="*"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
        processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```